# exchange 2007: reroute email for an internal user

Tags: email, exchange, exchange-2007, routing

Is there a way to have exchange catch all email from a certain internal user and redirect it to another internal mailbox, no matter who it is addressed to, internal or external?  Basically, we have an internal test environment that will be sending out workflow emails to various users internally.  We want to test the system using real addresses, but don't want any of the test emails to go to the users, but rather get redirected into a mailbox so we can verify the emails are being generated correctly without sending out tons of bogus internal emails.

Anybody had to do something like this before?  Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

you'd have to make a hub transport rule that checks the source mailbox and has an action of redirecting it to the other mailbox See [Getting to Know Transport Rules in Exchange 2007](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb421708.aspx)

I have to agree w/ Chris. If they are pulling them from AD then they'd get whatever addresses I give them access to.  Also note that this totally invalidates any testing that they are doing as far as mail routing goes- just whether or not the application can send email (which you can test yourself with a simple powershell/vbscript/batch file script).  If they are trying to see if the emails contain the right text I'd introduce them to a new programming concept I like to call "proofreading".  It's a bold new concept in which you actually read the code, and make sure it says what it's supposed to say before you compile it and introduce it to my production environment

Another lovely possibility is that when the app doesn't perform as expected, they will immediately ask you where your code sent the missing email.

Answer (score 1):

Jim B had it right. Open up The exchange Management Console, select Hub Transport and then select new transport rule from the action pane on the right hand side of the console.

Name your role, I personally would uncheck enable rule the first time you go through and then set your conditions, actions, and exceptions. It's exactly like rules and alerts in outlook.

For conditions you probably want to select from people pick the account you're testing with and then under actions select redirect the message to address and then select the mailbox you want the messages sent to. Doesn't seem like you need and exceptions so the whole process should take you 5 minutes to create. If you have multiple transport servers you might need to export the rule and then import it on other edge servers. All of this is in the article Jim B posted earlier.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do this, but a far better option is to create some internal test mailboxes, and test against those addresses.

Unless you're hard-coding the users email addresses into your application, this method is the least hassle, and a perfectly valid test.

Comment: I agree with you, but our developers application is pulling the email addys from AD and they don't want to change it.  There are like 50 - 80 addresses in various test systems and they'd have to go hand change them all.  I tried to talk them into the test mailbox option.. but you know developers...  :)  

So if you know how to do this, I'd appreciate it!  thanks